Kinesis GetRecords.Success metric suddenly dropped
I have adopted this pattern of Kinesis + Firehose + OpenSearch to collect metrics for my REST API. Long story short:

I have several REST API paths (e.g. /users, /users/{id}, /users/{id}/orders, and so on)
For each path I've set up a Kinesis + Firehose + OpenSearch index pipeline. For the purpose of this post, this is what I call a pipeline, an end-to-end combination of Kinesis + Firehose + OpenSearch index.
For each path's pipeline I've created several CloudWatch monitors to make sure my traffic flows correctly end-to-end.
My traffic is pretty steady and predictable. Most of my pipelines produce around 600 GetRecords.Success every 10 minutes.
Let's say I have 5 different pipelines with this traffic pattern.

The thing is, all of a sudden, on 2024-11-08 02:00 UTC, GetRecords.Success dropped from 600 to ~430 every 10 minutes. You may think "oh yeah your traffic has lowered as well". Well there are other Kinesis metrics that tell me the opposite.
These are facts for the different Kinesis streams:
GetRecords.Success is 100% for the last 7 days. Period. No issues.
GetRecords.Records (number of records being pulled from Kinesis) is totally normal for the last 7 days. No spikes, no drops, nothing, just normal.
PutRecords.Bytes  (number of bytes being put to Kinesis) is totally normal for the last 7 days. No spikes, no drops, nothing, just normal.
The only thing in front of Kinesis which is making GetRecords API calls to it is Firehose. My conclusion is that, if the number of successful calls to GetRecords is 100%, the number of records being pulled hasn't changed over time and the numner of bytes being put to the Kinesis stream hasn't change, then the only possible explanation is that Firehose is making less GetRecords API calls but pulling more records per call.
Please take a look at the drop, it is super abrupt.

